# Git log in cmake target

Tags: cmake

I have a custom target that puts a set of files into an archive, and I want to name this with the git log abbreviated version hash.

```
add_custom_target(deploy tar cvfz ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/archive-${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}.tar.gz -C ${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/ somecode.cpp )
```

I can get the hash using the following:

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND git log -1 --format=%h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

However, the variable GIT_COMMIT_HASH will not be changed after having run cmake for the first time, even if I push a new commit and then run the target again.

How can I do this so that whenever I run the target, the variable GIT_COMMIT_HASH will be updated? I couldn't see how to do this with custom commands as I couldn't get the contents of the command to be saved in a variable (or if the contents of the command are saved to a file, then reading the contents in the target becomes the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the contents of the command are saved to a file, then reading the contents in the target becomes the issue.

In `add_custom_target` *COMMAND* may be almost arbitrary **shell command line**, and use redirection and backticks for command substitution:

```
add_custom_target(deploy
    # This command will create 'archive_filename.txt' file with the full name of archive file inside
    COMMAND git --git-dir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} log -1 "--format=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/archive-%h.tar.gz" > archive_filename.txt
    # And this command will create the arhive file with a name,
    # taken from file 'archive_filename.txt'
    COMMAND tar cvfz `cat archive_filename.txt` -C ${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/ somecode.cpp
)
```

Code above passes to `--format` option for git not only `%h` specifier, but also remaining characters of the complete archive filename. Because of that, backticked argument in the further *COMMAND* is a *separate* shell argument. Alternative would be creating file with a complete archive filename as additional *COMMAND*:

```
add_custom_target(deploy
    # This command will create 'hash.txt' file with the commit's hash
    COMMAND git --git-dir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} log -1 --format=%h > hash.txt
    # This command will create 'archive_filename.txt' file with the full name of archive file inside, based on the commit's hash
    COMMAND printf "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/archive-%s.tar.gz" `cat hash.txt` > archive_filename.txt
    # And this command will create the arhive file with a name,
    # taken from file 'archive_filename.txt'
    COMMAND tar cvfz `cat archive_filename.txt` -C ${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/ somecode.cpp
)
```

Comment: I was trying to execute the command within the command using $(), which failed. It didn't occur to me to try with backticks instead. Thanks very much!

Comment: Note, that CMake transforms your `CMakeLists.txt` into Makefile, where `$()` has its own semantic. Maybe, escaping it like `\\$()` should help. (The first backslash is for CMake itself, the second is for Make).